# Постепенная отрисовка фигуры при зажатой клавише мыши (наподобие Paint'a) WinForms / C#

Tags: c#, winforms

День добрый, подскажите как реализовать постепенное рисование фигуры с коррекцией ее размера, как в пейнте, то есть когда я зажимаю кнопку мыши, я бы мог регулировать размер будущей фигуры.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572615/198316 почитайте, может наведет на нужные мысли.